# Visual Studio making text purple?

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, syntax-highlighting

Why does Visual Studio 2017 make some this text purple? I'd understand why it would do it if the entire word "pygame", but it only makes "game." purple.
It's been doing this to random parts of variable names when I declare them aswell.

[image: Purple text]

Comment: Huh, restarting Visual Studio seemed to work. It also fixed a lot of my "syntax errors" which weren't even errors and worked perfectly before. I wonder what that was all about.

Comment: No, its making "game.d,.t" purple.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about writing "game.x", but decided not to.